# Issue with [Url] data annotaiion

Tags: validation, blazor-server-side, data-annotations

Kind of new to data annotations for validation and need some help on a weird issue I am having.  This is a Blazor server application but not sure that makes any difference.  In my model I have many properties but this is where the issue is:

```
    [Url]
    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }
```

As you can see I do not have the [Required] attribute set as I just want to validate if there is text in the textbox.  It displays the error message as I would expect when a bad URL is entered:
[image]

Now, if I clear the textbox, the error still remains:
[image]

I want the validation error message to clear if the textbox is cleared after the validation message is displayed.  Even if I click my submit button, the message is still there.  How can I do this?

Thank you,
Jim

Comment: Why?  A blank field is an invalid value.  It initially doesn't show as invalid as no validation has been run.  Do you want to allow allow nulls?

Comment: Yes, I want to allow null or blanks.  For example, they type in an invalid url, but then decide they don't want to enter one at all.  This totally stops the page from submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems with is an issue with a few of the data annotation validator tags:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53820

It is strange to me because if I want the value to NOT be blank or null then [Required] should be used for this.  I understand the [Url] tag checks for correct format, but it should allow or have an option tag to allow blanks/nulls as well.

To get around this, I had to use RegEx validators for Urls and Email addresses.

Thanks all,
Jim

Comment: Are you using InputText or straight input for you edit control?  If `InputText`, you can build the functionality into a custom control. I'll show how if you wish.

Comment: Hi.  I am using MudBlazor controls, in this case a MudTextField.  But since I have it working another way, I don't want to waste your time.  Thank you though.